# sncf api , anyone gets how to request it?

Tags: api, authentication, get, token

https://data.sncf.com/api/en

"*HOW DO I USE MY AUTHENTIFICATION KEY ?

1. API Access : https://api.sncf.com/v1
2. Authenticate your Key
   Copy-paste your key in the field
   Leave the field blank
   **or insert your key directly into the URL***"

I want to insert the key in the URl (since I want to do a get request instead of typing the key in the browser directly), but I don't know what it means...

Here is the auth key I received: 0dca33cf-7a3b-4c16-9baf-534bbdaf98b6

Comment: You should keep your API Key for any site secure, never post it on a public site. Since you already posted it on a public site, you should request a new API key.

Answer (score 1):

Using curl :
curl -H "Authorization: 0dca33cf-7a3b-4c16-9baf-534bbdaf98b6" https://api.sncf.com/v1/coverage/sncf/lines

And BTW, avoid publishing private/personal keys online.

Answer (score 1):

To insert your key in the URI, instead typing it in the browser, you have 2 solutions :

1. You can use postman (Chrome extension, which allow you to deal with rest api) and put your key in the authorization > username field.
2. Or you can do that directly in the URI, [like this https://0dca33cf-7a3b-4c16-9baf-534bbdaf98b6@api.sncf.com/v1](https://0dca33cf-7a3b-4c16-9baf-534bbdaf98b6@api.sncf.com/v1)